Increase width of content column in Docusaurus
I'm using Dousaurus V3.
I want to increase the width of the center column where the markdown content i rendered.
The screenshow is from the Docusaurus docs site, which has a width of 990px. My own site has a width of 825px.
Probably using the custom.css file, how can I increase the width? And also account for mobile view and smaller screens.


Yes, you can override necessary styles in custom.css file.
Override following css custom properties based on your UI requirements:
--ifm-container-width-xl: 1320px (default value)
--ifm-container-width: 1140px (default value)

In your custom.css you can do like this:
:root {
  --ifm-container-width-xl: 1600px;
  --ifm-container-width: 1280px;
}

Don't forget to put correct width value as this is only example.
